Is Galatians 4.16 phrased as a question in the original Greek?
If we translate the Greek words verbatim, we see that Galatians 4.16 says, "so enemy of you have I become speaking truth to you." But every English translation I can find phrases this as a question rather than a declarative.
How do we know if a Greek sentence is a question? And is this one?

It would help if the question explicitly quoted some of the English translations.

The Greek is punctuated with a semicolon which is the question mark.

Ray Butterworth -- You'll see in my original question, I wrote "every English translation I could find." Go to BibleGateway.com, search for that verse, and then click underneath the verse on "view all English translations."

According to 'The Englishman's Greek New Testament' (Robert Estienne = Stevens) the literal Greek reads, "So enemy your have I become speaking truth to you;"
According to the Westcott & Hort Greek text the literal Greek reads "As-and enemy of you I have become speaking truth to you;"
According to the Nestle Greek Text (Marshall) the literal Greek reads, "So that an enemy of you have I become speaking truth to you;"
The renditions are in date order of Greek texts, the oldest being first.
If a semicolon in the Greek text indicates a question, then all of the above three renditions are correct to put a question-mark at the end of the second 'you', as they all do in the English.
But if that is not an inviolable rule of translating Greek, with some exceptions allowed, then those who know about such fine points would best answer. This matter was raised in an article asking whether Acts 26:28 was a statement, or a question. It pointed out that:

“It is true that the original Greek manuscripts did not have any
punctuation and that this was added by later editors. Nevertheless,
the fact that the editors never added the punctuation required to
indicate a question [in Acts 26:28 – a semicolon] clearly indicates
that they never understood it as such.” Quarterly Record, Issue No.
648, July to September 2024, article “Almost thou persuadest me to be
a Christian” by Larry Brigden, p.64, Trinitarian Bible Society

The case was being put for the A.V. being correct to have Agrippa make a statement to Paul, and not just a dismissive piece of banter or sarcasm, that required an exclamation mark. This is worth noting as modern translations not sticking to the ‘rule’ of translating the semicolon as requiring a question mark, for Acts 26:28 has no semicolon in the Greek text.
All I would add in this answer is that whether the Galatians sentence is taken to be a statement, or a question, appears to make no difference to the meaning, or the impact it was clearly designed by Paul to have on his Christian readership.

The form of a Greek question is  not necessarily different from a statement ; the punctuation and context are your main clues. William Mounce Basics of Biblical Greek. , p13 footnote 1.  ('Not necessarily' is the important bit.) Up-voted +1.

I believe the context of the statement may answer the question.  Paul is admonishing the Galatians for 'falling' back into a law based system of faith, as is clarified in the next chapter:
Galatians 5:4

Christ is become of no effect unto you, whosoever of you are justified by the law; ye are fallen from grace.

Prior to the verse in question (4:16), Paul states in verses 13-15, that when he first came to the Galatians they were not troubled by whatever Paul's "infirmity in the flesh" was.  It is irrelevant, but seemingly may have had something to do with his eyes, as they then "would have plucked out your own eyes, and have given them to" him (Gal 4:15).  They, at that first meeting, regarded Paul with high esteem regardless (verse 14 is key), but as he is reminding them of the truth and their error, he then questions if he has now rather become their enemy, as Paul's truth is contrary to their new belief (or reverting of faith) in being placed on their own self-righteous works of the law (Rom 10:3).
Paul, also in Galatians chapter 3, reminds them that it was by God's grace through their faith alone in Christ alone (Eph 2:8-9) that they were "made perfect" (2 Cor 5:21), and not by their own efforts in the flesh by following 'the law' or doctrines of men (Col 2:20-23).  Someone entered their church and introduced false doctrine, much like Peter did when bringing new Gentile believers into the law of circumcision:
Galatians 2:6-14

But of these who seemed to be somewhat, (whatsoever they were, it maketh no matter to me: God accepteth no man's person:) for they who seemed to be somewhat in conference added nothing to me:
7 But contrariwise, when they saw that the gospel of the uncircumcision was committed unto me, as the gospel of the circumcision was unto Peter;
8 (For he that wrought effectually in Peter to the apostleship of the circumcision, the same was mighty in me toward the Gentiles:)
9 And when James, Cephas, and John, who seemed to be pillars, perceived the grace that was given unto me, they gave to me and Barnabas the right hands of fellowship; that we should go unto the heathen, and they unto the circumcision.
10 Only they would that we should remember the poor; the same which I also was forward to do.
11 But when Peter was come to Antioch, I withstood him to the face, because he was to be blamed.
12 For before that certain came from James, he did eat with the Gentiles: but when they were come, he withdrew and separated himself, fearing them which were of the circumcision.
13 And the other Jews dissembled likewise with him; insomuch that Barnabas also was carried away with their dissimulation.
14 But when I saw that they walked not uprightly according to the truth of the gospel, I said unto Peter before them all, If thou, being a Jew, livest after the manner of Gentiles, and not as do the Jews, why compellest thou the Gentiles to live as do the Jews?

Galatians 3:1-3

O foolish Galatians, who hath bewitched you, that ye should not obey the truth, before whose eyes Jesus Christ hath been evidently set forth, crucified among you?
2 This only would I learn of you, Received ye the Spirit by the works of the law, or by the hearing of faith?
3 Are ye so foolish? having begun in the Spirit, are ye now made perfect by the flesh?

Paul addresses, in Galatians chapter 1, that any gospel other than the one they originally received of him is a perversion of the truth, so whether Paul is making the statement that they are now an enemy of his, or that he is now an enemy of them, (or questioning the premise) is actually true both ways.
Paul, concerning Israel and their need of repentance and baptism for their "times of refreshing" (Acts 3:19), compared to his "my gospel" for the church, the body of Christ, where spiritual "gifts and calling of God are without repentance", were intentionally contrary (as noted above in Galatians 2:7) for the purpose of 'provoking Israel to jealousy' due to their stumbling:
Romans 11:11

I say then, Have they stumbled that they should fall? God forbid: but rather through their fall salvation is come unto the Gentiles, for to provoke them to jealousy.

Romans 11:26-29

And so all Israel shall be saved: as it is written, There shall come out of Sion the Deliverer, and shall turn away ungodliness from Jacob:
27 For this is my covenant unto them, when I shall take away their sins.
28 As concerning the gospel, they are enemies for your sakes: but as touching the election, they are beloved for the father's sakes.
29 For the gifts and calling of God are without repentance.

I appreciate the question, as I too have always understood the verse to be a question, but in answering it I can see how it might actually be a statement.  I admit that my lack of knowledge in Greek grammar did not answer it specifically, but hope that by bringing in the full context, the significance of the verse is brought forth.

Thanks for the attempt, but I fully understood the chapter context and the whole book. My question was specifically about the construction of that one sentence. I believe that there is no reason to phrase that verse as an interrogative.
